# NodeMCU max draw

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

1) what is the max draw I can draw from NodeMCU V3 logic and 5v pins?
2) Also, I heard i draw with it more than 500mA, the PC USB port stops working. Is that information actual? Because USB 3 port has 900mA and USB 2 had 500mA max

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ... is what actual?

Answer (score 1):

for ESP8266 (which your NodeMCU is based upon) , the maximum current is about 20mA sinking and 12mA sourcing per [single] pin. so the maximum current of all GPIOs together is a lot lower than the 500mA USB limits.

you have to use external drivers (transistors, MOSFETs) for that purpose.

**Sink current**: the current which is provided when you pull the pin LOW. e.g. when you provide GND for the cathode of an LED. (the Anode is connected to VCC).

**Source current**: the current which is provided when you pull the pin HIGH. e.g. when you provide VCC for the anode of an LED. (the cathode is connected to GND).

*the difference is for different internal resistance for identical N-MOS/P-MOS, due to their structure. that's why many devices like 7segment drivers, or motor drivers supply GND for the Load (common anode drivers) instead of VCC.*

Comment: I would guess the question is not about the esp8266 io pins, but about the 3.3 V pin and the NodeMcu 3 on-board regulator

Comment: @Juraj it is said "logic" and 5v pins. It seems he means both of them

Comment: In that case, the Vin pin (which provides the 5 V from the USB cable) will be limited by the power source or cable and the 3.3 V rail provided by the NodeMCU i wouldn't draw more than about 300 mA from it. I don't know the rating of the actual component but looking at the package and amount of board area for heat dissipation i think that'd be a safe value for most ambient conditions.